# Python Seaborn jointplot does not show the correlation coefficient and p-value on the chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot jointplot with below and from samples I saw it should show the correlation coefficient and p-value on the chart. However it does not show those values on mine. Any advice? thanks.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid", color_codes=True)
sns.jointplot('Num of A', ' Ratio B', data = data_df, kind='reg', height=8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a code which can reproduce some figure to help you with. Also show us what you exactly want as the final figure. Currently you are just plotting the data. The samples you saw have probably displayed values using other means. One of them being `plt.text`. None of the plots on [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) page displays any values

Comment: Also, where are the examples that put the coefficients and p-value on the chart?

Comment: The feature of plotting the p-value has been removed from seaborn. You may still use the deprecated `stat_func` argument though. In general however, it is recommended that you calculate whatever value you want to show on the plot and add it via `ax.text`.

Comment: Thanks all. I can't quite figure how to use seaborn with ax.text so I end up using the annotate method of the Jointplot to show that.

Answer (score 37):

I ended up using below to plot

```
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats

sns.set(style="darkgrid", color_codes=True)
j = sns.jointplot('Num of A', ' Ratio B', data = data_df, kind='reg', height=8)
j.annotate(stats.pearsonr)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Underrated question/ answer pair. It's annoying that they unceremoniously deprecated `stat_func` and have no obvious workaround in the docs. I sense this SE post becoming much more popular with time…

Comment: Worked for me, but got this warning: `JointGrid annotation is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.`

Comment: UserWarning: JointGrid annotation is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
  warnings.warn(UserWarning(msg))

Comment: This is the [documented](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html) method (which maybe explains why few people have rated this Q/A pair more highly)

Answer (score 23):

With version >=0.11 of seaborn, jointgrid annotation is removed so you won't see the pearsonr value.

If needed to display, one way is to calculate the pearsonr and put it in the jointplot as a legend.

for example:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
graph = sns.jointplot(data=df,x='x', y='y')
r, p = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
# if you choose to write your own legend, then you should adjust the properties then
phantom, = graph.ax_joint.plot([], [], linestyle="", alpha=0)
# here graph is not a ax but a joint grid, so we access the axis through ax_joint method

graph.ax_joint.legend([phantom],['r={:f}, p={:f}'.format(r,p)])
```

[image]

Comment: So far this is the only answer that actually provides a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

This functionality was deprecated in Seaborn v0.9.0 (July 2018):

> Deprecated the statistical annotation component of JointGrid. The method is still available but will be removed in a future version. ([source](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html))

Comment: What is the exact reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore warnings for now. 
Also, we can directly call the annotate method on the plot without creating the object first.

```
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore')

sns.set(style="darkgrid", color_codes=True)
sns.jointplot('Num of A', ' Ratio B', data = data_df, kind='reg', height=8).annotate(stats.pearsonr)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn gives a parameter that helps with that

```
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stat
from warnings import filterwarnings

#this will help ignore warnings
filterwarnings ('ignore')

#jointplot

sns.jointplot('x', 'y', data=data, 
stat_func=stat.pearsonr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use annotation in seaborn, one way would be to do something like:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

sns.set(style="darkgrid", color_codes=True)
j = sns.jointplot('Num of A', ' Ratio B', data = data_df, kind='reg', height=8)
r, p = stats.pearsonr(data_df['Num of A'], data_used['Ratio B'])
# j.ax_joint allows me to access the matplotlib ax object, along with its
# associated methods and attributes
j.ax_joint.annotate('r = {:.2f} '.format(r), xy=(.1, .1), xycoords=ax.transAxes)
j.ax_joint.annotate('p = {:.2e}'.format(p), xy=(.4, .1), xycoords=ax.transAxes)
```

Comment: When I try this solution I recieve NameError: name 'ax' is not defined.

Comment: Hmm? Not sure what you man. I called j.ax_joint not j.ax so I dont see why you would get  'ax' is not defined. Are you using the latest version of seaborn? I am, or at least one of the newer versions, so maybe you can try updating your seaborn version? I realise some codes only work for updated seaborn versions

Comment: I use Jupyter Notebook so they should be updated.