# AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'stat_func'

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am currently working on data visualization.
I am using VS Code as my IDE.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats


mydata = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv')
sns.set()
sns.jointplot('age', 'fare', stat_func=stats.pearsonr, data=mydata)
```

I ran it using interactive-window and then I got this error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\DS\belajar\seaborn1.py in <module>
     20 
---> 21 sns.jointplot('age', 'fare', stat_func=stats.pearsonr, data=mydata)
|
|
(and many lines of errors here)
|
|
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'stat_func'
```

I also get a blank figure, without data visual or plotting or anything.  I have these:

- pandas 1.3.5
- seaborn 0.11.2
- matplotlib 3.5.1
- scipy 1.7.3

I read some opinions that it is caused by matplotlib version or something, but I can't find the right solution. How can I solve this issue?

ps: 'age' and 'fare' are the column titles in somedata.csv

Comment: See here: https://github.com/wdecoster/NanoPlot/issues/201.

Comment: The current version of [`sns.jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) doesn't support a `stat_func`.  You can add text via `g = sns.jointplot(...)` and `g.ax_joint.text(...)`.

Comment: See the second answer in [jointplot does not show the correlation coefficient and p-value on the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65785276/12046409)